# Android ListView onItemClickListener does not work on non-clickable EditText

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I got a ListView contains an ImageView and an EditText for each row. Both of them are non-clickable, but the onItemClick only work on ImageView, but not the EditText. Please help.

The following is the row of ListView:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_item_info"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_32"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_32" />

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_browser_item"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/browser_textview_style"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_image_textview"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Best regards,

Antony

Comment: Provide some Code and logcat please.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

on both of the views (Imageview and edittext)

Now you can able to select the imageview and edit the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use EditText and trying to block it? Just use TextView if you want to get unclickable EditText.